# Modern equivalent of the superiorto() function

Tags: matlab, class, object

I'm working on rewriting an old MATLAB package. As part of that rewrite I'm updating two classes (lets call them `old_class1` and `old_class2`) defined using the `class()` function to classes defined with classdef.

The definition of `old_class1` contains the line `superiorto('old_class2')`. This function is not allowed in a constructor defined with classdef, but I am unable to find any equivalent. How do I create functionality equivalent to `superiorto()` in a class defined with classdef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`superiorto` is no longer available in MATLAB, but I was able to find [a copy of old documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/object-precedence-in-expressions-using-operators.html) that indicates it was used to determine which object's method was called when multiple different classes were given as function arguments. For example, given `obj1=class1()` and `obj2=class2()`, with the `class1` constructor containing `superiorto('class2')`, would cause `function(obj1,obj2) to call`class1.function`, rather than`class2.function`.

With modern `classdef` functionality, the same can be accomplished by [setting the `InferiorClasses` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/object-precedence-in-expressions-using-operators.html):

```
classdef (InferiorClasses = {?class2}) class1
```